# How to properly proxy "inherited" static methods?

Tags: inheritance, dart, static-methods

I'm pretty new to Dart and still learning all the nuances it brings. One thing I'm really getting hung up on with my current task is inheriting (or proxying) static methods from a parent class.

```dart
void main() {
  EnglishCasual.greet();
}

class English {
  static greet() {
    actGreeting();
    sayGreeting();
  }

  static sayGreeting() {
    print('hello');
  }

  static actGreeting() {
    print('<tips hat>');
  }
}

class EnglishCasual extends English {
  static sayGreeting() {
    print("m'lady");
  }

  static actGreeting() {
    print('<tips fedora>');
  }
}
```

The above gives the error `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'greet'`, which, according to the Dart docs, is expected behavior, since static methods are not inherited (which seems odd to me, but ok. moving on...)

So then I tried a simple proxy to the parent class...

[DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a8c372f031536a00cb096a8bc79d5d5e)

But that yields another error: `Invalid context for 'super' invocation` or `'super' is only available in instance methods`. Ok... let's explicitly call the parent class by name.

[DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b8c65e621abc033b0579b20e40dd51a9)

But, as expected, that's just treated as any other call to `English.greet()` and we get a formal greeting instead of a casual one. Makes sense.

So then I turned to reflection. I found a snippet here on SO that seemed promising and put it to the test:

[DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/08d14858c007e5f4c0a1ca90bedf96c3)

Which resulted in an error `The method 'greet' is not defined for the class 'EnglishCasual'`, which I should have expected, since `noSuchMethod` wasn't defined as static, it wasn't getting called for static method calls. So, one last time...

[DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/eaf8ed6410d86296a24d687a0690fff3)

And we get another error `The name 'noSuchMethod' is already defined in 'core/object.dart'`.

At this point, I'm out of ideas. It seems that there is no way to accomplish this (seemingly simple) exercise, and I'm really hoping you guys can point me in the right direction.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Static methods are not inherited and can't be proxied AFAIK.

Comment: Just don't use static methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, static methods are not inherited. That means that only instance methods are inherited.
The only ways you can call two *different* functions with one call operation is if:

- it's invoking an instance method (incl. getters, setters and operators), or
- it's invoking a function value.

That is:

```dart
callA(o) => o.foo(42);  // Instance method.
callB(f) => f(42);  // Function value.
```

In *all* other situations, the function to call is determined statically, so you will always call exactly the same function. You can't make your `greet` function call different functions depending on how it's called unless it's an instance method itself or it takes a parameter that helps it choose.

In other words, don't try to do clever stuff with static functions.
You are trying to have the `CasualEnglish` versions of `sayGreeting` and `actGreeting` *override* the ones in `English`. That can only work if they are instance members.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is called "late static binding", at least in PHP that's what it's called. Basically, all the class hierarchies and inheritance is determined first, and after overrides are resolved/applied, THEN `static` is applied. Dart seems to be `static`-ing things early.

Comment: Late static binding only makes sense when statics are inherited, and in Dart they are not. Static members are no different from top-level members, they just use the class as a name-space. Since they are all statically resolved anyway, having the same function be available from two different classes wasn't seen as an advantage, you can always access the correct one directly.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not inherited in Dart, can't be overridden etc.

Open the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf) and search for *10.7 Static Methods*.

Comment: Yes, I stated this in my original question, too. I'm looking for another way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete "static" keywords - inheritance and overrides will start to work, as shown in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4c0e7904e7eccabb6ae62353564b6d51).

I recommend to step back and look at Object Oriented Programming (OOP) concepts, luckily you can use [Java OOP basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) as Dart is similar in this case, class based object oriented language. You may also check what dart guru [Seth Ladd](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/02/classes-in-dart-part-one.html) and more generally [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) are saying.